# redirect_to an instance variable does not work in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm completely new to Rails. Just started from *http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
While trying I'm stuck with redirect_to problem like below error -

```
NoMethodError in SwversionsController#create
undefined method `sw_versions_url' for #<SwversionsController:0xa38d158>
Rails.root: C:/Sites/edisonprojectmanagement
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/swversions_controller.rb:19:in `create'*
```

This error occurs after clicking submit button. I found the model is working fine and data is saved in my postgresql database. 
I think problem is with my redirect_to method.

My SwVersionsController code looks like -

```
class SwversionsController < ApplicationController
def index

end
def show
    @swversion = SwVersion.find(params[:id])

end
def new

end

def create
    @swversion = SwVersion.new(swversion_params)
    @swversion.save
    redirect_to @swversion
end

private
def swversion_params
    params.require(:swversion).permit(:sw_version, :description)
end
end
```

And the new.html.erb code is -

```
<h1> New SW versions </h1>
<%= form_for :swversion, url: swversions_path do |f| %>
<p>
 <%= f.label :sw_version, "SW Version" %> <br>
 <%= f.text_field :sw_version %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :description, "Description" %> <br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
</p>
<% end  %>
```

My routes.rb is pretty simple

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :swversions
  get 'welcome/index

Someone please help me to banish this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `sw_versions_url' for SwversionsController:0xa38d158

***Naming Conventions:***

Rails is very strict in naming and for a good reason. Rails expects the class names to be ***CamelCase*** and the methods/variables to be ***snake_case***.

Your ***model class name*** is `SwVersion`, so the method/variable name should be `sw_version` not `swversion`. So you should change `swversion` to `sw_version` in your entire code

You should also change the ***controller class name*** to `SwVersionsController`.

And also if you have `resources :swversions` in `routes.rb`, then you should change it to `resources :sw_versions`

More about ***naming conventions*** [***here***](https://gist.github.com/iangreenleaf/b206d09c587e8fc6399e)

Comment: Exactly Pavan . Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
redirect_to sw_version_path(@swversion)
```

Comment: share your routes file.